# How do I load CSV file to Amazon Athena that contains JSON field

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a CSV (tab separated) in s3 that needs to be queried on a JSON field.

```
uid\tname\taddress
1\tmoorthi\t{"rno":123,"code":400111}
2\tkiranp\t{"rno":124,"street":"kemp road"}
```

How can I query this data in Amazon Athena?

I should be able to query like:

```
select uid
from table1
where address['street']="kemp road";
```

Comment: I would guess you could use a AWS-Glue crawler to crawl the data, and it will automatically infer the schema for you, recognizing that your address column contains json data. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the `json_extract()` command.

From [Extracting Data from JSON - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html):

> You may have source data with containing JSON-encoded strings that you do not necessarily want to deserialize into a table in Athena. In this case, you can still run SQL operations on this data, using the JSON functions available in Presto.

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{"name": "Susan Smith",
           "org": "engineering",
           "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},
           {"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
    AS blob
)
SELECT
  json_extract(blob, '$.name') AS name,
  json_extract(blob, '$.projects') AS projects
FROM dataset
```

This example shows how `json_extract()` can be used to extract fields from JSON. Thus, you *might* be able to do something like:

```
select uid
from table1
where json_extract(address, '$.street') = "kemp road";
```

Comment: You may have to use 'CROSS JOIN UNNEST'. I'm not quite sure it applies to this exact use-case.